# Eliminate tick labels on the y-axis

Tags: plotting, graphics

How do I eliminate the tick labels on the y-axis but keep the frame label?

My graph:

[image]

I want to achieve this:

[image]

My code:

```
Plot[{2 Cos[2 - (15 x)/2] Cos[x/2], 2 Cos[x/2], -2 Cos[x/2]}, {x, 0, 
  15}, FrameStyle -> FontSize -> 14, FrameLabel -> {"x", "t"}, 
 RotateLabel -> False, Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, False}}, 
 Axes -> False, 
 PlotStyle -> {ColorData[97, "ColorList"][[;; 1]], {Black, 
    Dashed}, {Black, Dashed}}, AspectRatio -> 1/4, ImageSize -> 500]
```

Comment: Read about `Ticks` and `TicksLabel`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the internal function `` Charting`ScaledFrameTicks `` to produce ticks without labels:

```
Plot[
    {2 Cos[2-(15 x)/2] Cos[x/2],2 Cos[x/2],-2 Cos[x/2]},
    {x,0,15},
    FrameStyle->FontSize->14,
    FrameLabel->{"x","t"},
    RotateLabel->False,
    Frame->{{True,False},{True,False}},
    FrameTicks->{{Charting`ScaledFrameTicks[{Identity,Identity}],None},{Automatic,None}},
    PlotStyle->{Automatic,{Black,Dashed},{Black,Dashed}},
    AspectRatio->1/4,
    ImageSize->500
]
```

[image]